# How to update ListViewItem.SelectedItem whenever the ListView child control gets focus?

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm, selecteditem, childcontrol

How to udpate the `ListView.SelectedItem` when a child control within the `ListView` gets focus?

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Records, Mode=TwoWay}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
     <ListView.SelectedItem>
          <Binding Path="SelectedRecord" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
     </ListView.SelectedItem>
     <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
          <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
               <Style.Triggers>
                   <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                         <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                   </Trigger>
               </Style.Triggers>
          </Style>
     </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
     <ListView.Resources>
          <DataTemplate DataType="x:Type ListViewItem">
               <ListViewItem IsSelected="{Binding IsKeyboardFocusWithin"/>
          </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.Resources>
     <ListView.View>
          <GridView>
              <GridViewColumn>
              <TextBox ... Tag="{Binding}".../>
              </GridViewColumn>
              <GridViewColumn>
              <TextBox ... Tag="{Binding}".../>
              </GridViewColumn>
          </GridView>
     </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

The `ListView` has rows of child controls within the `GridView` columns. I want to update the bound property of the `ListView.SelectedItem` when any of the child control in any row has the keyboard focus. It will be great if this could be entirely done within the `.xaml` file without having to resort to the code-behind.

Answer (score 6):

Change the [SelectionMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.selectionmode) of your `ListBox` to `Single`

Your current code works if you don't set the default `SelectedItem`, however if you set the default `SelectedItem` then it doesn't automatically unselect it when you click on a 2nd item, so `SelectedItem` stays bound to the default selected item until you give that row focus and remove it again.

You can also simplify your XAML a bit. You don't need the `DataTemplate` in your `ListBoxItem.Resources` and you can set the `SelectedItem` in your `<ListBox>` tag directly

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Records}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRecord}" SelectionMode="Single">

     <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
          <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
               <Style.Triggers>
                   <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                         <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                   </Trigger>
               </Style.Triggers>
          </Style>
     </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

     <ListView.View>
          <GridView>
              <GridViewColumn>
              <TextBox ... Tag="{Binding}".../>
              </GridViewColumn>
              <GridViewColumn>
              <TextBox ... Tag="{Binding}".../>
              </GridViewColumn>
          </GridView>
     </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```